# Crossfade Image Fade In and Out with match images

Tags: jquery, css

I have problem regarding with the slide. Is there any way i can see the images fade in and out..

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevpao22/gn8c7sb7) is a fiddle.

```
function cycleImages(){

      var $active = $('#cycler .active');
      var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
// run every 4s
setInterval('cycleImages()', 4000);
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/webdevpao22/gn8c7sb7/

Comment: Matching Images, you mean the same yes??

Comment: Yes.. Same images but i cant see it fade in and out.. can you please help me?

Comment: The problem is you are fading out in the same image so you want see a fade. let me see if we can do it using a different approach

Comment: How about this, Just fade out in one image and have another behind it with less opacity -- http://jsfiddle.net/bnm615vq/

Comment: Cool ill put it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

you have a start, I think you will be able to figure it out once you change this:

```
setInterval('cycleImages()', 4000);
```

to this:

```
setInterval(function(){cycleImages()}, 4000);
```

Then fix your code from there.

Comment: Still not working.. Can you give me a sample fiddle of this?? http://jsfiddle.net/webdevpao22/gn8c7sb7/3/

Comment: You are using jQuery so you have to bring it in. In the left column at the top, where it says Frameworks and Extensions, click the drop down that says "No-Library (Pure JS)", from the drop down, select jQuery 2.1.0

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm.. Im still new to stack overflow. Thank you again..